# npm install keep removing package

Tags: angular, npm

I have two packages `ngx-infinite-scroll` and `ngx-bar-rating` when I install the first one, the second removed. and the same thing if I install the second one.

```
Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.1.4
... cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/core              7.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.1.4
@angular/animations               7.2.0
@angular/cdk                      7.2.1
@angular/material                 7.2.1
@ngtools/webpack                  7.1.4
@schematics/angular               7.1.4
@schematics/update                0.11.4
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.23.1
```

Comment: Are they in your package.json? Install the packages with the --save flag to add them to the list of dependencies: `npm install --save ngx-bar-rating`

Comment: @JimmyHedström I tried but same thing, They remove each other